# Override event properties

Tags: javascript, performance

How can I override event properties? The reason I'm doing this is because I want to override properties like `pageX` on mouse event and that property is read-only.

I first tried this

```
context.addEventListener(type, function (e) {
    var Event;

    Event = function () {

        this.pageX = pageX;
        this.pageY = pageY;

        this.preventDefault = function () {
            e.preventDefault();
        };

        this.stopPropagation = function () {
            e.stopPropagation();
        };

        this.stopImmediatePropagation = function () {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        };
    };

    Event.prototype = e;

    callback.call(context, new Event());
}, false);
```

Unfortunately, it's too good to be true. It's not working on some browsers (Chrome at least). Property `pageX` cannot be set because read-only state is somehow inherited from event object.

Then I tried

```
context.addEventListener(type, function (e) {
    var evt = {},
        i;

    for (i in e) {
        if (e.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            evt[i] = e[i];
        }
    }

    evt.pageX = pageX;
    evt.pageY = pageY;

    evt.preventDefault = function () {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    evt.stopPropagation = function () {
        e.stopPropagation();
    };

    evt.stopImmediatePropagation = function () {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    };

    callback.call(context, evt);
}, false);
```

This one works, but is about 100 times slower than first method. I really would not want to go this way or I will feel bad every time I use it.

I considered about giving up. I could just add property like `pointX` to original event and add value of `pageX` there. Then again, if some browser decides to add property `pointX` and make it read-only, all my code will be broken.

Any advice would be most welcome.

Update: Now it works thanks to Esailija! I add solution here below.

```
document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    var Event = function () {};

    Event.prototype = e;

    Event = new Event();

    Object.defineProperty(Event, 'pageX', {
        value: 999
    });

    console.log(Event);

}, false);
```

Comment: The inheritance of read-only is per spec, you need to use `defineProperty` if you want to ignore possible getters, setters and read-only for same named property in the prototype.

Comment: Thank you so much for this one! I still have to do some tests to find out which would be the most performant way, but this helps ALOT. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Property pageX cannot be set because read-only state is somehow inherited from event object.

You can overrule that assignment behavior by using [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

And instead of the custom, only once used constructor you should go for [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). It even has a second argument that works like [`defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties), so you can shorten your code to

```
context.addEventListener(type, function (e) {
    callback.call(context, Object.create(e, {
        pageX: {value: pageX /* configurable, enumerable, writable? */},
        pageY: {value: pageY /* configurable, enumerable, writable? */}
    }));
    // I'd guess you don't even need the explicit "super" calls
    // for preventDefault, stopPropagation and stopImmediatePropagation
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested this a little bit and it seems to be a little bit faster than creating new constructor every time. :)

Comment: @MattiMehtonen but that's not a fair test since you can easily move the constructor out of run-time code by making it statically and using prototype from `document.createEvent("MouseEvents")`. Example http://jsfiddle.net/mtjhm/

Comment: @MattiMehtonen here's even better example that should perform the best if you don't retrieve any properties because they are retrieved lazily through a getter http://jsfiddle.net/mtjhm/1/

Comment: @Esailija thank you! Constructor of your example is 3 times faster than my best current alternative. But the problem here is that property getters comes a little bit slower and at the end, overall performance is best in my current version. My current implementation has problem that all properties are not easily available, but I think it's ok. Simple tests can be found here http://jsperf.com/event-object

Comment: @MattiMehtonen your jsperf is very much incorrect, it merely tests the performance of `.addEventlistener`. See here http://jsperf.com/event-object/2 <-- same code in each test but very different results due to incorrect tests... you need to just compare pure js code instantiating a constructor instead of using DOM like that.

Comment: Fixed that. It did affect the results...how's that possible since all tests did include the same addEventListener?

Comment: @MattiMehtonen You kept accumulating eventlisteners on the dom without clearing them up in-between. You could consider that test2 started with 100000 eventlisteners already added in the dom, thus adding new ones kept getting slower and slower. Test1 started with 0 so it was fastest.

Comment: @MattiMehtonen here's proper jsperf test case http://jsperf.com/event-object/3. I should add the lazy one there (the one in jsfiddle) because it will surely be the fastest

Comment: @Esailija Thanks you so much for your help! I think this case is closed. :D

Comment: @MattiMehtonen My MouseEvent (TestD) is indeed fastest: http://jsperf.com/event-object/4 even when invoking the getters for both (worst case)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the benefit in creating a new class/function from scratch with every event that will get fired. You could simply write a wrapper class.

http://jsfiddle.net/F6Urw/1/

```
document.getElementById('button')
    .addEventListener('click', click);

function click(e) {
    var wrapper = new EventWrapper(e);
    console.log(wrapper.pointX);
    console.log(wrapper.pointY);
}

function EventWrapper(event) {
    this.pointX = event.pageX;
    this.pointY = event.pageY;
    this.originalEvent = event;
}
```

Comment: I actually came to the same conclusion. At least jQuery and YUI does it more or less like this. Thank you for advice! :)