# Cant set properties of created event object in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, properties, mousewheel

I hope I'm doing everything right on my first post!
I stuck trying to create a JS event which I would dispatch later.
I realized that I couldn't set the properties of the event, so I ended up playing around in the browser console, but I can't get it to work.

This is my code I execute:

```js
var e = new WheelEvent('mousewheel');
e.wheelDelta = 1;
console.log(e.wheelDelta);
```

As the result shows, the wheelDelta property is still zero.
I feel like an idiot right now, would appreciate any help!

Edit:
Since it seems to be related to Chrome and the event to be obsolete, I tried the same with 'click' and bubbles, which should be supported on every browser. Same issue...

```js
var e = new Event('click');
e.bubbles = true;
console.log(e.bubbles);
```

SOLVED:
I found out the properties were somehow read-only.
Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026722/override-event-properties) solved this.

Comment: Its 1 for me...

Comment: Weird. I just tested it on Firefox and it works. So it seems to be a Chrome issue...

Comment: I have the same problem, but you might want to reconsider using that event as it is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousewheel_event

Comment: I have read about that too, but since I am writing a contentscript which has to fire a event of the original page javascript, i unfortunately don't have this option. Anyway, thanks for the help.